# Set value to a property on GET request

Tags: vue-resource, vuejs2

Trying to update a value of vue property based on server response:

```
  @registration = new Vue(
    el: '#calculator_calendar'
    data:
      constraints:
        amount:
          min: null
          max: null
```

and method where I do GET request

```
 loadConstraints: () ->
    @$http.get(constraintsUrl).then ((response) ->
      @$set 'constraints.amount.min', response.data.constraints.amount.min
```

what is the correct syntax to update `constraints.amount,min`.

With older versions used to do

```
@$set 'constraints.amount.min', response.data.constraints.amount.max
```

but it doesn't work anymore, fails with

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot create property '100' on string 'constraints.amount.min'
```

**versions:**

- Vue v2.0.8
- vue-resource v1.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign it, like it is done in javascript:

```
 loadConstraints: () => {
    var vm = this
    $http.get(constraintsUrl).then ((response) =>
      vm.constraints.amount.min' = response.data.constraints.amount.min
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but won't this affect the way reactive works? They say in that link "vm.b = 2
// `vm.b` is NOT reactive". https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Anyway, I guess I will just go this way for now, if no other answer will be added soon I'll accept it. Thank you

Comment: @rmagnum2002 if `b` is not defined in [data](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) attributes, in that case `vm.b` will not be reactive, however as you have already defined your `constraints.amount.min` in your data, it should be reactive. You can see if this is reactive or not if it is rendering in the view.